# Why is the app crashing on this activity?

Tags: android, admob

On some devices the app crashes when the user presses the button that leads to the activity that has to load this ad.

And this is from the device(coolpad with 4.2 android) on which the app crashes:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2358)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2410)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600 (ActivityThread.java:169)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1380)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5463)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:854)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:621)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:746)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:749)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:749)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:749)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:489)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:396)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:352)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
  at com.akademos.user.secondtry.QuizActivity.onCreate (QuizActivity.java:52)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5122)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2322)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2098)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable (TypedArray.java:601)
  at android.view.View.<init> (View.java:3380)
  at android.widget.TextView.<init> (TextView.java:608)
  at android.widget.Button.<init> (Button.java:107)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init> (AppCompatButton.java:66)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init> (AppCompatButton.java:62)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView (LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:675)
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: 
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner (Drawable.java:881)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml (Drawable.java:822)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2094)
```

Here is the xml that might be causing the problem:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/load"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/load"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
```

Comment: Do you have logcat from the crashes?

Comment: No, well the crashes are not the only problem if you could tell me why it never loads the ad on my device?

Comment: You should limit your questions to 1 problem per question, especially since we can't really help with the crash without the logcat. (And yes, I do know how much of a pain it is to get your users to click the "report" button)

Comment: Okay, I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InflateException` means that your XML layout could not be created. This is usually caused by a wrong XML syntax / wrong parameters.

`Resources$NotFoundException` indicates, that some resource could not be found by the system. Maybe you are using `View` Elements which are not supported by older Android versions. If possible, please include the XML layout of the view which you try to show.

Comment: Okay i added the xml that might be causing problems

Comment: @TodorValkov According to their git page, this view element requires android 4.0, which should be fine. Can you post the whole XML layout file of the activity which you try to show?

Comment: [link](https://codeshare.io/29mrQ4) I can't edit the question because it says that I have too much code. That is why I posted the xml on this website.

Comment: @TodorValkov Can you past the content of the `effectrippleradiobutton` resource? I assume that removing / replacing `android:background="@drawable/effectrippleradiobutton"` with another background will fix the problem.

Comment: [link](https://codeshare.io/29mrQ4) Here I posted on the bottom of link.
Also when i opened the xml file there was error saying "preview timed out " or something like this.

Comment: Okay I fixed it. I just deleted the ripple effect and made it a normal looking button. Thank you very much.